# Browser timout: the server at example.com is taking too long to respond

Tags: javascript, php, firefox, download, connection-timeout

On the client side a user clicks a download button, the (apache) webserver (and PHP5.4) then creates a very large file which upon completion must be send to the client side. Because it takes a while to create this (huge) file the browser (FF) after 5 minutes prompt with the message: "The connection has timed out: the server at 10.0.0.100 is taking too long to respond".

On my php page I've set a large timeout: set_time_limit(3600); but this doesn't help. I tried echo-ing a white space before the server generates the file, to let the browser know there is a response, but that trick sends the content of the file into the browser itself which is not what I want.

As headers I am using, but I think this is not the issue as the browser times-out before anything is sent from the server :

```
$size=  filesize($path);
$fname = basename ($path);    
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$fname."\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".$size);
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($path);
exit;
```

Any ideas on how to solve this problem? Maybe there is a javascript way?

Answer (score 2):

I would start the file creation via ajax (call generate.php), display a message to the client "your file is being generated, and will download when ready. Please do not close your browser".

In generate.php, when done set some kind of flag, eg update a database, save a file to disk etc.

After the initial ajax to generate.php, periodically (say every 30 seconds) make an ajax request to check.php, which checks for the flag mentioned above.

If found, the file uri is returned to the calling js, which can then download it (set window.location, or src of a hidden iframe)